# How to view ~ (tilde) instead of home directory in bash?

Tags: bash, home, tilde

I've changed my home directory from `/home/alessandro` to `/mnt/c/Users/aless/Documents/uni/labcalc` (I am using debian in WSL so `/mnt/c` is `C:\` in windows). When I type `cd ~` it correctly goes to my new home directory but in bash the full path is shown and not just `~$`. How can i fix this?

UPDATE:
My $PS1 variable is:
`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

Comment: What is the output of `echo $HOME` and `echo $PS1`?

Comment: if `$HOME` is wrong, change it with `usermod -d /mnt/c/...  $USER`.  If `$PS1` is empty or doesn't contain `\w`, then you may need to copy `~/.bashrc` from your old home to the new one.

Comment: I must assume that you are talking about what's shown in your command line prompt, right?  What does `printf '%s\n' "$PS1"` output?

Comment: I have updated the question with the $PS1 variable so it's there for everybody. It seems as if option \w is set. $HOME displays the correct path

Answer (score 1):

What Bash shows in the prompt depends entirely on what is set in `PS1`. The prompt escape `\w` (or `\W`) would show the current directory (or the last part of it), but with the home directory shown as `~`. Using `$PWD` would show the unmodified working directory. (Both show it as used in the `cd` command, this matters if you `cd` to a directory via a symlink.)

Answer (score 0):

After looking on the web it seems that my $PS1 variable is set correctly. I guess it's a WSL problem or a Windows Terminal problem.